# What is genodiversity good for?

Tags: genetics, sexual-selection

I saw some documents which were trying to say that they can prove via sweat smell selected by women that humans are developed to find a partner with similar genes. At the first glance, I refused it as absurd for many examples of organisms behaving in reverse but then I realized that I don't know any satisfying evolutionary explanation for this (and more: I could even explain the contrary: If less developed and more developed human had a baby, the better genes could be maybe annulled by the worse genes, on the contrary two very developed partners would have not only a lot of descendants, but their descendants would have also lot of descendants and so on.)

And more thing: if genetic diversity is truly evolutionary practical, could for example even people with genetically transmitted disease help our gene pool?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should add a link to that document.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Sorry, I've seen it in TV and I can't find it anymore (apart from   the fact that the document was in czech :-)

Comment: Identification of potential partners by body odors is actually selecting for *different* genes, not similar ones - see this article on "[genetic matchmaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_matchmaking)" for some additional details.

Comment: @MattDMo Yeah, that's what I though, in that document was definitely the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

Genetic diversity is indeed very important for many reasons, most notably resistance to diseases.

The [Gros Michel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gros_Michel_banana) banana used to be the most cultivated banana, until it was almost completely wiped out by a fungal disease due to lack of resistance in the genetically homogenous cultivars grown in plantations. As a result, it had to be replaced by the [Cavendish banana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_bananas) across most of its former range by banana growers.

Furthermore, the answer is a definite "yes" to people with genetically transmitted diseases helping the gene pool.

For example, the case of [sickle cell anemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sickle-cell_disease) clearly shows why even people with genetic diseases can help the gene pool by providing useful alleles. Heterozygotes for the sickle cell allele are [resistant to malaria](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0952791509000788). This has led to the allele having a high propensity in subsaharan Africa, where malaria is endemic.

> The first example of genetically controlled innate resistance to human malaria was the demonstration in 1954 that sickle-cell heterozygotes have less severe Plasmodium falciparum infections than do children with normal adult hemoglobin. This observation has been repeatedly confirmed, most recently by independent studies of genome-wide associations in severe falciparum malaria, which have identified the HBB locus as the major signal of association.

Additional examples are the [cystic fibrosis gene](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/biology/b103/f02/web1/emyers.html), which confers resistance to cholera, and [thalassemia](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1196/annals.1345.068/abstract), which confers resistance to heart attacks.